# Multiple markers at this line error

Tags: c, header

*Multiple markers at this line
    - previous definition of 'type' was here
    - redefinition of parameter 'type'*

> ```
> int parseLine(char* line, int* day, float* amount,char* type, char* type);
> ```

That's the error I'm getting in a header C file in Eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error tells you that you defined `char* type` twice

Answer (score 2):

You are using the variable name `type` twice.

Replace line with some different name

```
int parseLine(char* line, int* day, float* amount,char* type, char* type2);
```